# Error 500: Hosting .net Core 6 app into IIS on Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2016

Before opening this ticket, I read dozens of other questions here on StackOverflow, youtube etc, but all suggestions that I found not solve my problem.

What I intend is to host a .net core 6 web api on windows server 2016 using IIS.
I've managed to host a client site (Angular) without problems, but the API always gives me a 500.19 error:

[image]

I have configured port 5041, but I have already tried with others, such as 80, 8080 without success.

**I already have installed the Asp.Net Core Runtime and Hosting Bundle:**

[image]

**This is my web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\EvoStats.API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I saw someone else who solved your problem by putting the full path of dotnet, I did that too, **but it didn't solve in my case**:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...
```

**I also configured the Application Pool to not manage the code using .net CLR**

[image]

I don't know what I can do more :(

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe you can find more information in Windows Event Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already managed to solve it.

The problem was with the access permissions to the wwwroot folder.
Something strange, because I have a site (Angular) working on this folder, before giving **Full Control** to the user IIS_IUSRS.

[image]

Hope this solution helps others.

Comment: This answer is suspicious, as if `IIS_IUSRS` lacks of access to that folder the "Error Code" should be `0x80070005`.

Comment: I also find it strange, but it was since I gave full control to IIS_IUSRS user, that the error disappeared and the app started to run